# FilternameFilter en Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una programa que busque los nombres de archivos en un directoria y necesito pasar como parametro un String que indique parte del nombre del archivo, pero que no necesariamente inicie con ese parametro. Por ejemplo, paso el parametro "123456", y me devuelve los semejantes, como abc123456, 123456abc, etc.
Agradecería si alguien puede ayudarme.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, utilicé el método containts(parametro)

Comment: Recomendaría que en lugar de un comentario pudieras redactar una respuesta. Revisa [answer].

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [`File#listFiles(FilenameFilter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles-java.io.FilenameFilter-) para obtener los archivos y aplicar un filtro para los nombres a obtener:

```
public File[] obtenerArchivosFiltrados(File carpetaBase, String nombre) {
    return carpetaBase.listFiles( (f, s) -> s.contains(nombre) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizar esto si utilizas Java 8 :

```
    public static List<String> buscaCoincidencia(List<String> listaArchivos,String palabraClave)
    {
       listaArchivos.removeIf((s -> !s.contains(palabraClave)));
       return listaArchivos;
    }
```